# Как в CMake подключить библиотеку libbacktrace?

Tags: c++, cmake, линковка

Пишу проект под linux с использованием GCC и CMake. Для правильной работы boost::stacktrace понадобилось подключить библиотеку libbacktrace. Как это сделать в CMake?

Пробовал так:

```
find_library (BACKTRACE_LIBRARY libbacktrace) 
target_link_libraries(${BACKTRACE_LIBRARY})
```

---

#### Upd: Ниже будет находится актуальный CMake скрипт которым я пытаюсь собрать проект.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(fast_test_3)
add_definitions(-DBUILD_TYPE_="${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
add_definitions(-DPROJECT_NAME_="${PROJECT_NAME}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread ") #
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -g -DDREAL_DEBUG -DDREAL_TRACE -fno-inline")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL      "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -O2 -g")

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})

#------------ Подключение Backtrace -------------------
find_package(Backtrace REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#-----------------------------------------------------


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "foo.h" "foo.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} ${Backtrace_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: А как / где у вас находится файлы библиотеки libbacktrace?

Comment: @VTT я не знаю =). Я запулил исходники с [этого](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) репозитория, собрал и сделал make install. Ссылку на этот репозитория я [нашёл](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html) в официальном описании boost::stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль [FindBacktrace](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/FindBacktrace.html) создает переменные:

- `Backtrace_FOUND` - признак того, что библиотека найдена
- `Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIRS` - путь к заголовочным файлам
- `Backtrace_LIBRARIES` - флаги линковщика

Можно наипсать что-то вроде этого:

```
find_package(Backtrace) 
if(NOT Backtrace_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Backtrace is not found")
endif()

target_link_libraries(MyTraget PUBLIC ${Backtrace_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(MyTraget PUBLIC ${Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Хотя это, конечно, одноразовое решение. Если у вас миллион таргетов, то можно один раз создать интерфейсную библиотеку:

```
find_package(Backtrace) 
if(NOT Backtrace_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Backtrace is not found")
endif()

add_library(Backtrace INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(Backtrace INTERFACE ${Backtrace_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(Backtrace INTERFACE ${Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

А потом использовать ее так:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTraget PUBLIC Backtrace)
```

**PS**: Код писал в браузере, могут быть ошибки.

Comment: Модуль FindBacktrace у меня присутствует. Cmake не может найти саму либу, но это уже другой вопрос, сейчас буду с ним разбирается, главное, что вы показали правильный синтаксис. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: Собралось. Только я target_link_libraries  заменил на link_libraries.

Comment: Извиняюсь что ввёл в заблуждение, на самом деле не линкуется. т.е. это пока не помогло. Буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: @mrFieldy, не надо так. `link_libraries` добавляет эту библиотеку во все таргеты. Лучше явно указывать там, где она нужна. _The target_link_libraries() command should be preferred whenever possible._

Comment: @mrFieldy, уточните что не так. Посмотрте что находится в `${Backtrace_LIBRARIES}`. Та ли эта библиотека, которую вы ожидаете

Comment: я добавил в вопрос отредактированный CMake скрипт которым я пытаюсь собрать. На данном этапе у меня сыпятся ошибки при линковке: undefined reference to <какие-то функции из backtrace>. Переменная Backtrace_LIBRARIES пуста, хотя Backtrace_FOUND = true.

Comment: Тут все основывается на предпосылке, что есть соотв. cmake пакет и библиотека является установленной (в терминологии cmake). Вместо волшебного блока `if(NOT Backtrace_FOUND)` можно воспользоваться волшебной директивой `find_package(Backtrace REQUIRED)` чтобы cmake сам ругнулся

Comment: @VTT Обновил CMake скрипт в вопросе. В выводе не чего не поменялось. Сам Cmake парсится успешно, но на этапе линковки неопределённые ссылки на функции.

Comment: @mrFieldy, а где ваша библиотека находится? Есть ли этот путь в `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`?

Comment: После выполнения make-install у либы в консольном выводе присутсвует следующая строка `Libraries have been installed in: /usr/local/lib`. Вот что содержит CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH: `/usr/local;/usr;/;/usr/local;/usr/local;/usr/X11R6;/usr/pkg;/opt`.

Comment: @mrFieldy, мистика какая-то. CMake ищет библиотеки в `${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH}/lib`. В вашем случае это как раз `/usr/local/lib`. Все должно работать. Попробуйте очистить кэш CMake и запустить разбор еще раз. Если это не поможет, то я сдаюсь :)